# Run gitlab runner in debug mode doesnt work

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I tried to run my gitlab runner in debug mode like this :

```
docker run --restart unless-stopped --volume /var/lib/gitlab-runner:/etc/gitlab-runner \
  --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --detach \
  --name gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest --debug
```

But when I try to get the status I always have this :

```
Error response from daemon: Container e3c3a58fdb5b5a2b06939280ddf2b17448cc9ef9fb221c752fa425a990b05f12 is restarting, wait until the container is running
```

How can I set debug mode to a running runner ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In docker run command, anything after image:tag is command to run in the container on startup.

You are running --debug, that will result in command not found.

Use something like this:

```
docker run --restart unless-stopped --volume /var/lib/gitlab-runner:/etc/gitlab-runner--volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --detach --name gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest gitlab-runner --debug <command>
```